# Error appears when curselection bind to ListBox returns empty tuple after clicking in other widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I have an issue with curselection of ListBox. It appears in Python 3.6. In Python 3.4 everything works fine. My code selects items from ListBox and put it in Entry widget. It works perfectly well when i click on the items in ListBox. But sometimes (after 5-10 clicks) when I click in Entry widget an error appears:

> _tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number

Here's my code sample:

```
   from tkinter import *

def insert_into_entry(event):
    index=list_box.curselection()
    print(index)
    selected_item=list_box.get(index)
    entry1.delete(0,END)
    entry1.insert(END,selected_item)

window=Tk()
entry=Entry(window)
entry.grid(row=0,column=0)

list_box=Listbox(window,height=5,width=45)
list_box.grid(row=1,column=0)
list_box.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',insert_into_entry)

entry1=Entry(window)
entry1.grid(row=2,column=0)

a=['one','two','three','four']
for i in a:
    list_box.insert(END,i)

window.mainloop()
```

I tried to examine changes in index value. And error brings about when after clicking in Entry widget index returns empty tuple. It's my first question so I'll be greatfull for every response.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error. I cant say off the top of my head what is wrong with it but I will play around with it for a while to see what I can find.

Comment: Just to be clear: you're saying that to reproduce this we have to click 5-10 times in the listbox and then click in the entry widget?

Comment: If you add `exportselection=False` to the options when creating the listbox, does the error go away?

Comment: I added updated my answer with what I think is the best way to fix this issue. @BryanOakley I was hoping you could provide feedback on this one. I think I have the issue figured out but I would like to know if you have a more correct way to resolve the issue as I am not sure if my answer is the correct way or just a bandage fix..

Comment: @BryanOakley Error occurs when you first select item from listbox, and after that click few times Entry widget. And after adding 'exportselection=False' into options of ListBox, issue doesn't appear. So problem seems to be resolved! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see by testing `<<ListboxSelect>>` I believe that the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event activates every time the selection changes even if that selection changes to "nothing selected". I believe this is why when you click off of the listbox and into any other field and the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event is triggered your `insert_into_entry` function is getting an empty tuple from `curselection()`.
According to the documentation [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm) the `courselection()` method will return an empty tuple if nothing is selected.

To avoid any errors we can first check if the results of `ndex = list_box.curselection()` are not equal to `()` an empty tuple. If not then perform the rest of the function. This should prevent any errors caused by this behaviour with the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event being called outside of the listbox.

Oh and one other thing. Don't use built in names for variable names. change `index = list_box.curselection()` to something like `ndex = list_box.curselection()`

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()

def insert_into_entry(Event = None):
    ndex = list_box.curselection()
    if ndex != ():
        selected_item=list_box.get(ndex)
        entry1.delete(0,END)
        entry1.insert(END,selected_item)


entry=Entry(window)
entry.grid(row=0,column=0)

list_box=Listbox(window,height=5,width=45)
list_box.grid(row=1,column=0)
list_box.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', insert_into_entry)

entry1=Entry(window)
entry1.grid(row=2,column=0)

a=['one','two','three','four']
for i in a:
    list_box.insert(END,i)

window.mainloop()
```